# iPhone 4s change Apple id

Tags: iphone

A friend has given me his old iPhone but it still has his Apple id on iTunes and the cloud and won't allow me access. How do I erase this and input my details instead

Comment: iCloud, messages, facetime, iTunes and Appstore and game center are all locations in settings where logins using appleId's exist.  All of them need to be changed to your appleID.   If findmyiPhone is activated the previous owner will need to supply his password in order to log out of iCloud.  You might also want to consider wiping the phone and setting it up from scratch (Settings > Reset > Erase all content and settings), however again you will need the previous owners appleid password if findmyiPhone is active.

Comment: Have your friend read through this & unlock the device, then wipe it & start with your own fresh Apple ID - https://support.apple.com/en-is/HT201351

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Settings > iTunes & App Store**, click on the Apple ID at the top and you will be presented with the option to sign out of the currently logged-in account. Sign in with your account and you will then be able to add your own apps, music etc.