# How can I restore an ipad mini without an apple id password?

Tags: ipad, restore

My mom bought this ipad mini for herself but didn't like it and gave it to me...now I'm trying to restore it to factory settings, but when I try it says it needs her apple id password - only it won't accept it - says it's incorrect. How can I restore it without the apple id password?

Comment: If findmyiPhone is enabled, you can't.  Head over to iforgot.apple.com and with your mothers help get the password figured out.

Comment: See [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177631/) or [that](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177415/) or [perhaps this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177279/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need to have the apple id password for both reseting from iTunes and from the device itself. If the device isn't accepting the apple id password, try reseting it from iTunes too. iTunes is more reliable and you can reset without the **device password** (not the apple id password) on iTunes.